# SceneKit dae file loss texture in device but works fine in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

I exported the dae file which contains built-in texture from Maya and added it into Xcode. It looks fine in finder and Xcode, even in simulator. However, it's texture doesn't appear in my iPhone.

Here is the screenshot of my simulator. You can see a colorful chair, wall and gate.

[image]

This is the screenshot of my iphone. Can anyone tell me how can the same code behave differently in simulator and my device?

[image]

Comment: Not all devices support all texture sizes - are the dimensions a power of 2?

Comment: @Kenny One of the texture(the green part of wall)  isn't. So I manually use a modified picture(256 * 256) as the geometry's diffuse property. Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes I doubted it too since none of the textures work. Could be several other things: are the texture files present and loaded properly on the iPhone? Do you use custom shaders, and are they supported on the iPhone? Do you check for errors on your GL calls?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no custom shaders. I just create a default SceneKit project and drag `wall.dae` into the scn file and put it near the plane. It also seems no errors on GL calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something wrong with relative path. I really didn't figure out this wired problem but my solution is to export dae file **without** texture, then drag the png into Xcode and set the geometry's diffuse property.

If you use Maya and ColladaMaya plugin, try to check "relative path" when exporting dae file.